# Concurrent Ajax calls in CakePHP results in lost session

Tags: php, ajax, session, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP 2.x and implemented an AJAX file uploader `(lpology.com/code/ajaxuploader/)`.

It works fine except when I have more than one instance of it on the screen uploading files at the same time. If I upload one after another it works fine, but when I do more than one at once then one of them works and the other comes up with an invalid session issue on the server side of the call.

From what I can tell and from what Google tells me, it seems that my session is being locked on the first AJAX call and then the second one comes along and can't authenticate so it errors out.

I've tried using all the different session options that people have tried but to no avail including database sessions, memcached etc.

No idea where to go from here in order to get this working for concurrent AJAX requests to upload files?

EDIT #1:

On every page request I noticed that the following is in the response headers:

```
Set-Cookie:CAKEPHP=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie:CAKEPHP=0rlaq85cf0k16o8d1kki345g34; expires=Sun, 20-Apr-2014 04:33:32 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
```

Looks like it's deleting the CAKEPHP session cookie on every request. How can I stop it doing this?

EDIT #2:

Found it! In the `beforeFilter()` of the appController I renew the Auth array by relogging in the user so it's constantly up to date. This causes a new session ID to be generated.